# How to pick out specific elements in css

Tags: html, css

I just require someone with a little bit of CSS know how on how to grab specific elements from the HTML.

So really what I need is to hide all menus from within a footer only. Now there are other menus on the site so I need to point specifically to menus in the footer only. I simply want to state `display:none` for these footer menus.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this? My main issue is how to pick it out from within the footer. I am guessing we can do a check class contains word menu but haven't been able to get it to work.

Below is the html, so there are 6 aside tags and 4 should display none which are the ones that contains word "menu" in the class:

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">
  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <div class="columns_wrap">
        <aside id="text-4"></aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu "></aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu "></aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu "></aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu "></aside>
        <aside id="custom_html-3 " class="widget_text widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_custom_html "></aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Just use the _descendant combinator_ …? `footer .widget_nav_menu`

Comment: I made you a snippet. You had a `"` in text-4 too many and missed all the end divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS looking at partial class

```css
footer [class*=menu] { display:none }
```

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">
  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <div class="columns_wrap">
        <aside id="text-4">Show</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="custom_html-3 " class="widget_text widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_custom_html ">Show</aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS using the ID

```css
footer aside[id*=menu] { display:none }
```

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">
  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <div class="columns_wrap">
        <aside id="text-4">Show</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="custom_html-3 " class="widget_text widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_custom_html ">Show</aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

JavaScript to look at the className

```js
document.querySelectorAll("footer aside").forEach(aside => {
  if (aside.className.includes("menu")) aside.setAttribute("hidden", true)
})
```

```html
<footer class="footer_wrap widget_area scheme_original">
  <div class="footer_wrap_inner widget_area_inner">
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <div class="columns_wrap">
        <aside id="text-4">Show</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-6" class="widget_number_8 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-7" class="widget_number_9 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-8" class="widget_number_10 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-9" class="widget_number_11 column-1_5 widget widget_nav_menu ">Hide</aside>
        <aside id="custom_html-3 " class="widget_text widget_number_12 column-1_5 widget widget_custom_html ">Show</aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```